# Android Gradle - Where to add "android.debug.obsoleteApi=true"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I updated to AndroidStudio 3.3 which now gives a warning about deprecated libraries:

> WARNING: API 'variant.getExternalNativeBuildTasks()' is obsolete and
>   has been replaced with 'variant.getExternalNativeBuildProviders()'. It
>   will be removed at the end of 2019. For more information, see
>   https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance. To
>   determine what is calling variant.getExternalNativeBuildTasks(), use
>   -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display a stack trace. Affected Modules: app

There is some more info provided at their web site:

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin?utm_source=android-studio#behavior_changes

but I don't exactly understand it. They say:

> To see the additional info, you need to include the following in your
>   project's gradle.properties file:
>
> android.debug.obsoleteApi=true

So I took the build.gradle that is marked with (Project: [my project])

The document looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.10'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
        classpath 'com.github.triplet.gradle:play-publisher:1.1.5'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

project.ext.preDexLibs = !project.hasProperty('disablePreDex')

subprojects {
    project.plugins.whenPluginAdded { plugin ->
        if ("com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin" == plugin.class.name) {
            project.android.dexOptions.preDexLibraries = rootProject.ext.preDexLibs
        } else if ("com.android.build.gradle.LibraryPlugin" == plugin.class.name) {
            project.android.dexOptions.preDexLibraries = rootProject.ext.preDexLibs
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

However, I don't understand, where I should add that line now. And no matter where I put it, I always get an error.

E.g. when writing it directly in the first line:

> Could not get unknown property 'android' for root project [my project]
>   of type org.gradle.api.Project.

So where is this supposed to be added? Or am I mixing the definitions of "Project" and "app" for the gradle files?

Comment: Now that you know the solution for this, have you find the solution for the warning? I am having the same issue with variant.getMergeResources() which is obsolete. I could use any hint for this. Thanks!

Comment: To be honest, I haven't had a look at this issue for a while but let me know once you find out anything. :)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You need to put it in `gradle.properties` file which is present at the project level, outside of the app folder **not** in `build.gradle` file which you are currently trying to do.

From the android developer documentation

> Better debug info when using obsolete API: When the plugin detects that you're using an API that's no longer supported, it can now provide more-detailed information to help you determine where that API is being used. To see the additional info, **you need to include the following in your project's gradle.properties file**:
>
> android.debug.obsoleteApi=true
> You can also enable the flag by passing -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true from the command line.

You can check this [Link](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin).

Comment: Thanks, that was my mistake!

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: Is it the same as 'gradle-wrapper.properties' file ?

Comment: @Regis_AG No, they are not. More information can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48701867/some-light-on-gradle-properties-settings-gradle-gradle-wrapper-properties-and

Answer (score 11):

The easiest way is do it in the **terminal** at the root of the android project.

Run the following command:

```
 ./gradlew -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true
```

Answer (score 4):

As stated in the error message, you should add that in `gradle.properties` file and **not** in any of your `build.gradle` files

Comment: Thanks for the hint. That was the solution.