# How to execute command in Android Studio?

Tags: android, gradle, command

when I build my project on Android Studio. In Build log, it shows

> AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"API 'BaseVariant.getApplicationIdTextResource' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'VariantProperties.applicationId'.\nIt will be removed in version 7.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.\nFor more information, see TBD.\nTo determine what is calling BaseVariant.getApplicationIdTextResource, use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more information.","sources":[{}]}

Thus, my question is. how can I execute command `-Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true` in Android Studio? so that i can see further info. Thank you in advance!.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Gradle - Where to add "android.debug.obsoleteApi=true"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54198773/android-gradle-where-to-add-android-debug-obsoleteapi-true)